# Problem related to classification of surfaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Given a $2-$ dimensional connected finite $CW$ complex $X$ with $H_1(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and Euler characteristics 1, is there any option other than $\mathbb{RP}^2\vee \mathbb{RP}^2$ up to homotopy? There is also a surjection from $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to \pi_1(X)$.

I have tried to conclude above by classification of two surfaces. Is this a correct approach?

I am almost convinced but could not give proof. Is there a way to show it is the wedge of two $\mathbb{RP}^2$ or is it something else?

Comment: If you want a surface, $\Bbb RP^2\vee \Bbb RP^2$ doesn't qualify.

Comment: @Elliot G I don't want a surface. I just want a 2-CW complex that satisfies those properties. So far in my mind, I can see only one example without proof!!

Comment: Wedging with an acyclic, non-contractible, 2-dimensional finite CW-complex (such a thing is constructed in Hatcher) leaves your homological conditions unaltered, but will in general change the homotopy type of $X$, so you do need some homotopy-theoretic hypotheses. Note also that Euler characteristic 1 is equivalent to $H_2(X)=0$ and that we can explicitly construct a cellular map $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2\vee\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2\rightarrow X$ inducing isos on homology, but we need hypotheses on what this does on the level of homotopy groups to get sth like a Whitehead theorem.